# Magento Paypal "Unable to initialize Express Checkout."

Tags: paypal

I go through the payment checkout procedure and get to the PayPal website and I sign in with an account click “Pay” and PayPal takes me back to the Magento shopping cart. after selecting the order button i get  an error “Unable to initialize Express Checkout.” What does that mean and how i can fix this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There's a few things that can cause this.  Can you update your question with your php error log and magento log?

Comment: Also, provide the version of Magento and the theme you are using. If your template is overriding `paypal/express`, it could have introduce a bug.